# Altium Designer: Modify IC symbols in-sheet to increase space

Tags: altium

I am using some schematic symbols for TI devices that I converted to Altium using the Ultra Librarian Software as "instructed" by TI.

However all of these symbols are too crammed, I already have trouble attaching the rudimentary decoupling capacitors to the pins.

I could of course change the symbol in the library, however this would be a very time consuming iterative process until it fits my schematic. Is is possible in Altium to "in-sheet" redesign the part symbol?

Example of crammed component:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No

We have started to always think of an application case to design a "nice", useful symbol. Takes some time but it's absolutely worth it.

Of course, this will not always fit your use case, but it's the best you can get; plus, you can re-use it for other schematics.

Examples:

- Place VDD and GND pins such that you can easily place a cap in between, maybe even in an extra sub-component if there are many of those.
- Place pins in groups so you can easily place a harness or bus, ..

I got interrupted yesterday, so I quit this post early.

In fact, it is possible to move pins (double click the symbol, then deselect "Lock Pins") but you will lose all those changes if you perform a library update, plus you cannot edit any of the other primitives.